# How to setup ServiceStack ServerEvents with Redis backpane geographically distributed

Tags: redis, servicestack

My situation is this:

Site "A" (Romania): multiple apphost (1 per PC) exanging serverevents using Redis Backpane.
Site "B" (Turkey): multiple apphost (1 per PC) exanging serverevents using Redis Backpane.

Now, I need to create on Site "0" (italy) a "collector" of all sites serverevents.  How can I do it?  Is it possible?

I am using ServiceStack 5.4.0 with MSOpenTech Redis 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack's [Redis Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-server-events) lets you connect to a Redis Master instance either directly or via [Redis Sentinel](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-sentinel) but doesn't support having AppHosts connect to the same geographically distributed Redis cluster.

Comment: I'm a little confused and, propably, I explain my needs in the wrong way.  I don't want to let apphosts on site "a" connect to other redis server than the one on site "a", I'm just wondering how I can collect all server events coming from each site.  I need a kind of "global collector"

Comment: @EnricoGobbo Server Events is transient data so it's not clear what the purpose of collecting the data in a single location would be, but I'd start by looking at [How to Backup and Restore Open Source Redis](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-Backup-and-Restore-Open-Source-Redis).

Comment: you are right, it is not clear and it's my fault.  I try to explain again, hopefully better: on site "0" how can I get event raised on site "A" and site "B"?  I need just this...

Comment: @EnricoGobbo You can't easily. Redis pub/sub events are transient, you'd need to connect to all redis servers simultaneously and use the [Redis Pub/Sub Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#managed-pubsub-server) to monitor the `sse:topic` Redis topic.

Comment: Ah ok... it seems to be easier to connect to one of the apphost of every site and listen to their events.  right?

Comment: @EnricoGobbo yeah that would be easier.